# Proving that $\text{tr}^2(A) - 4\det(A) \geq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I'm trying to figure out how to prove that when given a diagonal matrix

\begin{align}
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda & 0\\
0 & \mu
\end{bmatrix},
\end{align}
with a positive determinant $\det(A) > 0$, the following statement is true
$$\text{tr}^2(A) - 4\det(A) \geq 0$$
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried writing the trace and determinant in terms of $\lambda$ and $\mu$ and then doing a little algebra?

Comment: I have, I get $\frac{\lambda^2+\mu^2-2\lambda\mu}{4}>\lambda\mu.$... I can't really figure what to do from here.

Comment: I think you've slipped up in your algebra. Also, that $\lambda^2+\mu^2-2\lambda\mu$ looks familiar....

Comment: It looks like a second degree polynomial. But I'm thrown off by the additional quadratic term.

Comment: Algebra, algebra! Please, please, please check your algebra!

Comment: Oh my, it should be $\lambda^2+\mu^2+2\lambda\mu$ at least.

Comment: What is the referent of "it"?

Comment: The expansion of the quadratic term tr(A)^2.. So $\lambda^2+\mu^2+2\lambda\mu\geq 4\lambda\mu$ which the implies $\lambda^2+\mu^2-2\lambda\mu\geq 0$. Simplifying further gets $(\lambda-\mu)^2\geq0$. I'm not quite sure what this is telling me.

Comment: By George! I think he's got it!

Answer (score 2):

More generally, the characteristic polynomial of a $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ is  $x^2-\operatorname{tr}(A)x + \det(A)$. The roots of this polynomial are the eigenvalues of $A$ and so are real iff the discriminant $\operatorname{tr}(A)^2 -4\det(A)$ is nonnegative.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :**

**Simply using the definitions of $\text{tr}$ and $\det$ :**

The trace of the matrix $A$, is :

$$\text{tr}(A) = \lambda + \mu $$

The determinant of $A$, simply is :

$$\det(A) = \lambda \mu$$

Can you now follow a simple algebraic path to $\text{tr}^2(A) - 4\det(A)$ and conclude about its sign ? Use also the condition that as you stated, the determinant is positive.

Answer (score -1):

$\begin{align}
tr(A)^2-4 \det(A)\geq 0
\end{align} \iff (\lambda + \mu)^2 \ge 4 \lambda \mu \iff \lambda^2 -2 \lambda \mu + \mu^2 \ge 0 \iff (\lambda- \mu)^2 \ge 0$.

Comment: Simply elaborated, but why give a thorough solution to a simple problem of which the OP have showed zero attempts ?

Comment: Not leaving much for OP to do, Fred.